# Does the wavefunction probabilities have to sum to 1?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, unitarity, born-rule

In quantum mechanics we are often told that $\int |\psi(x,t)|^2 dx^3 =1$.
i.e. the probabilities have to sum to 1. And that this implies the time evolution operator is unitary.

But can't we define the probability as:

$$P(x,t) = \frac{|\psi(x,t)|^2}{\int |\psi(x,t)|^2 dx^3}$$

Then the probabilities would still add up to 1.

But then we needn't have a unitary time evolution operator. In fact wouldn't any complex operator do?

What am I missing here?

e.g. could you have a time evolution operator like $U(t)=2^t$

Comment: you can define the prob. as you do but why do it this way?  You still have to compute $\int \vert \psi\vert^2$ so no savings.  You might as well set it to one and be done with it.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero but what then is the equivalent of Unitarity?

Comment: unitarity preserves the norm, whatever that norm is.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero So instead of $U^\dagger U=1$ you could have $U^\dagger U$ just has to be a real number. (is that right?) Is there a name for such a matrix?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156367/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167099/50583 (for (un)normalized states), https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169936/50583 (for why we need unitarity)

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement is all **physical** wave functions must normalizable (and hence once normalized integrate to 1). Note that is is almost *always* what is meant by "wave function". The set of all such functions is called the **Hilbert space**.

**Time evolution**: As per your question about having non-unitary time evolution. Such a time evolution would not be physical, as it would not preserve the norm of the state. Namely, if we had some time evolution operator such that

$$\langle \psi| V^\dagger V | \psi \rangle \neq \langle \psi | \psi \rangle$$

Then that would imply that if we at some point had a probability of 1 **to find the particle somewhere**, then at some time later there would be some nonzero probability that **we wouldn't find the particle anywhere** (i.e. it would just "vanish"). Such a situation is unphysical.