# Normalization of a wave function in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, normalization

A more simple question, so I am watching a quantum mechanics lecture on potentials of free particles and am doing the general solution of schrodinger's stationary equation for a free particle when I was told to normalize the solution (which I can do all well and good) but I have no idea what it actually means to "normalize" 
My question being what is normalization ? What does its product describe ?

Comment: You can multiply a wave-function $\psi$ by any constant and it will still describe the same physical state. However, the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) tells us that the square $|\psi|^2$ corresponds to a probability. And so it follows that the integral $\int |\psi|^2$ over all possible states must be 1. Normalisation is just scaling $\psi$ by a constant to make sure this integral is indeed unity.

Comment: @lemon, shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: what is meant by an integral being unity ?

Comment: @darren "unity" is a (uselessly complicated) way that a lot of physicists say "one". When they say something is unity, they mean that thing is equal to one.

Comment: Related: [Who is doing the normalization of wave function in the time evolution of wave function?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156367/50583)

Comment: so what does this show if the integral is unity ?

Comment: @darren That the square $|\psi|^2$ can be interpreted as a probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Born's rule: the probability density of finding a particle in a certain place is proportional to its square absolute value.

To change the "is proportional to" to "is", you multiply the wave function by a constant so that the absolute value squared integrates to 1, and so acts as a probability density function.

That's called *normalisation*, or *normalising the wave function*.

Answer (score -1):

One peculiar fact about a ***real life***  wave function $\psi$ is that it ***can*** be normalized. In order to analyze and compare the various outcomes of the solution of a Schrodinger  equation, one need to assign a quality that is unique to all the wave functions, that which is to transform them such that their area is always 1.

Comment: Wrong, if you always divide by the norms in the probability amplitude, you don't need to normalize at all.

Comment: what is a **real life** wave function anyway?

Comment: @ACuriousMind True, still the statement is valid, whether you know the norm or not.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Solution to potentials that don't have an infinity in a local space.